# How can I convert FlowChart to PHP Code and vise versa in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'am new to Enterprise Architect, and I need to know if EA supports converting flowchart to php code and vise versa?, and if it doesn't are there any alternatives?

Comment: How would you convert a flowchart to code anyway? A flowchart tells you how it shall run, not how to code it.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I think it could be because every node in flow chart is represent a statement in the code, like decision node in flow chart is a "if statement" in code.
plus I have already found online tool that is convert code to flow chart but does not support php language, and here is the tool link  http://code2flow.com/  and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyllTdCkvEE

Comment: Well, just ignoring my personal thoughts about FCs,  the tool creates a FC from code, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Furqan.

Here is a link to the Sparx web page on generating code from behavioral models.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/software_engineering/code_generation_from_behaviora.html

EA includes native support for PHP (see under Tools | Options | Source Code Engineering). The nearest thing to a traditional flowchart in EA is the Activity Diagram. You could try creating an Activity Diagram then use the information on the Sparx web page to generate PHP from that. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have Found this [tool](http://flowchart-to-code.en.softonic.com/) which convert Flow Chart to pseudo code, and export pseudo code to multiple languages, but it Does not support PHP.

and the [other](http://code2flow.com/) tool is converting code to Flowchart

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with PSeint, (you work with pseudocode that then translates to php), it's free but in spanish, unfortunately.

http://pseint.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think that the question was about how to do it in EA app, but if I got it correctly, you are just suggesting alternative tool, that have it's own "pseudo language", of course it's for the @userx to decide, but I guess you could either provide more details  on how to use suggested app, or find a way to transform EA output to suggested app`s pseudocode